# Where to include jQuery in Ionic index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a strange problem here.

I am working on a Ionic (AngularJS) project and using jQuery in one of my controllers, so need to add the reference to it in index.html

If I add reference like this -

```
<!-- jQuery js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

then, I get below error from one of the views -

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ionTabs', required by directive 'ionTabNav', can't be found!
```

But, If I add reference like this -

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

then, I get below error from another one of the controllers, which was the reason I included jQuery in the first place -

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!
```

Not sure how to resolve this? I need to get both functionalities working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a conflict between ionic and certain versions of jQuery . https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1976 - switching the version of jQuery you are using should resolve.

Comment: Oh man! I hope this gets resolved soon. I switched to jQuery 1.11.2 and included it before ionic.bundle.js statement.

Comment: i had the same issue, adding jquery before ionic.bundle.js fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that the problem here is not with a conflict between ionic (per se) and jQuery, but an issue with Angular and jQuery.

Angular comes with a jQlite version of jQuery and that's probably what is conflicting. You might get some more information from [this post on the Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/use-ionic-with-jquery/1120/9).

Sorry I can't be more helpful, I'm only just starting out on my ionic adventures myself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery Lite. Read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element